# iPhone COUNT going up in increments of 3

Tags: iphone, count

I've managed to get my app to count the number of actions on an IBAction button, and then perform a different task once the number of clicks exceeds 10.

Unfortunately, the Count seems to be increasing by 3 at a time, instead of 1.

Any ideas what I've done wrong here?

```
- (IBAction) do_button_press:(id)sender {
    static int count = 0;
    count++;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d\n", count];

    if (count++ > 10) {
        label.text = @"done";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a NSLog() and see what is going on...are you getting called multiple times?

Comment: the `int count = 0;` part inside the method, will cause it to always be 1?

Comment: No, that's an initialization of a static local variable. It happens only once.

Comment: Interesting, shows how little I know about Obj-C :-)

Comment: @Sander:  That code does the same thing in C++, Java, C#, and PHP also.

Comment: Not really, you don't declare static variables inside methods bodies there?

Comment: Got it all sorted no guys, thanks for all the comments/answers. Simple change which resulted in everything working as expected. I blame the late night and lack of coffee :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't your `if` statement look like:

```
if (count > 10)
```

rather than:

```
if (count++ > 10)
```

?

Using your original code, the first time `count` is used, its value is 1, then incremented to 2 (by the `count++` in the `if` statement), then incremented to 3 (by the `count++` in line 3)

Comment: That's certainly part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two "count++" in your method, so you're incrementing count at least twice.

`- (IBAction) do_button_press:(id)sender {
     static int count = 0;
     label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d\n", count];
     if (count++ > 10) {
         label.text = @"done";
     }
 }`

Just remove the first count++.

Comment: thanks for the answer, got it all sorted. just a late night i think!